# Pack gem with app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I have a simple app/script wich depends on a single gem and what I want to do is to pack it with the app so there is no need to install it each time on every new machine it needs to run.

I tried with bundler pack command but the problem is that this way I still need to have bundler installed which I can't assure.

So what a made was grab the code I need from the gem and then used it.

---

### My question is:

How can I pack the gem with my app without any dependency and is my current solution is polite?

Cheers

Comment: adding the lib folder of the gem into your applications lib folder should do the trick

Comment: Can you make an answer about that? How to load it then?

Comment: any specific gem? i could give u a example with that

Comment: It just have a module it should be the simplest case.

Comment: then i think u are good to go with putting it in lib as rails will autoload lib directory. u can just user ModuleName::ClassName.method anywhere in your application

Comment: This is not a rails app. Its a simple script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from setup.rb(or wherever the entry point of your application) add this line:

```
Dir.glob("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/*.rb") { |lib| require lib }
```